# Store data and component data isn't the same (vuex + persisted state)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

Here is my `post.js` in `store`:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate"

export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        sample_data: 'Welcome!!',
        logged_in: false,
    },
    getters: {
        getSampleData: state => state.sample_data
    },
    mutations: {

   },
    actions: {

    },

}
```

And in my component:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    <p>{{ sample_data }}</p>
    <p>{{ logged_in }}</p>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {

  },
  data() {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome'
    }
  },
  methods: {

  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState('post', ['sample_data', 'logged_in'])
  }
}
</script>
```

I have installed the Vue extension in Chrome.
Now when I change the `sample_data` in `DevTools > Vue > Vuex` from *"welcome"* to *"welcome 2222"*, it will exactly say *"welcome 2222"* on the page. Now when I hit refresh, the page goes back in saying *"welcome"* but in the Vuex panel it says the `sample_data: welcome 2222`. I tried refreshing the Vue panel but it will still say `sample_data: welcome 2222` so the persisted state must be working. Why is my page though displays the old *"welcome"* and not the *"welcome 2222"*?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I tried putting this:

```
mutations: {
    setSampleData(state, payload) {
        state.sample_data = payload
    }
},
actions: {
    setSampleData({commit}, payload) {
        commit('setSampleData', payload)
    }
},
```

And in my component:

```
<button @click="setSampleData('Hello Hero')">Get Data</button>
```

Now it changed the state to "Hello Hero" even if I refresh the page. It seems to be working. However again, in the Vuex panel, it will still say something like "welcome 2222".

If I change the data in the Vuex panel to "hi there", the page will say "hi there". But when I refresh, it will display "Hello Hero" again and in the Vuex panel it says "hi there". Seems there's a problem between the two?

**UPDATE 2**

`store/index.js`

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import post from './post'
import createPersistedState from "vuex-persistedstate"
import * as Cookies from 'js-cookie'

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  modules: {
    post
  },
  plugins: [createPersistedState()],
})
```

Comment: Are you changing it from Vue extension ? Am I right ?

Comment: @omerS Yes and I'm using Chrome

Comment: I think, you should add plugins while creating store, Check out [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate#vuex-persistedstate-3x-for-vuex-3-and-vue-2) once

Comment: @Naren yes I have already done that. I noticed something bizarre too - I put this on my router `let logged_in = post.state.logged_in` and filters a certain page to only be accessed if `logged_in` is `true`. When I call an action to set the `logged_in` to `true`, it will set it. However I cannot access that certain protected page.

Comment: @omerS yes I have already done that. I noticed something bizarre too - I put this on my router `let logged_in = post.state.logged_in` and filters a certain page to only be accessed if `logged_in` is `true`. When I call an action to set the `logged_in` to `true`, it will set it. However I cannot access that certain protected page.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you didn't meet this requirement from the package documentation:

> New plugin instances can be created in separate files, but must be imported and added to plugins object in the main Vuex file

Comment: I don't see the main Vuex file and the code where you registreting Vuex store

Comment: So you see, you created 2 persisted states one in the main Vuex file and one in the store module `post.js`. You should name the second one something like `post`: `createPersistedState({
  paths: ['posts']
})` and you should do it in the main Store file.

Comment: I removed the second one (post.js) and added the `paths...` code on the main store. The problem is still there. It seems there are 2 different states going on idk

Comment: And if you leave one one createPersistedState() in `store/index.js`?

Comment: You can check state in browser dev tools to see what's going on there and what was stored

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224337/discussion-between-dran-dev-and-anatoly).